# How to find the date and time representation for the different locales?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I want to test a date&time field on sharepoint 2010, and check if it can show correctly the date/time format according to the site locale.
But I don't know what the correct format should be for some locales. IS there any list for me to check it? I only found [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc824907%28v=office.14%29.aspx) on msdn, but it's only showing the locale ids.
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

very summarize answer is:

same as Excel ... same as access ...

if you or your users know which format is correct in excel or access you can customize that in SharePoint.

this is my to do list :

1- install and configure Language packs

2- configure other calendars and priorities in setting

3- apply those Internet Explorer settings by Group Policy in domain controller

4- for date and time formats : according to your needs you can configure and show them in format you want in Excel and then show in excel services web part.

ultimately you can create access view if cant customize in sharepoint.

for auto configure browsers when users open SharePoint sites, use Group policy.

if you want to seek items with compare date >> create view >> and filter date field  [today]-30 in your queries.

Comment: This answer seems incomplete, like you posted it before it was completely written? :)

Comment: ooopppps. corrected. but i dont know why